# How to Deploy Angular 7 Project to Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, angular7, gcloud

I have built an Angular 7 application that works nicely when I do the `ng serve` command from my local mac or from a remote centos server.

This application is using `php` files that access MySQL data base both served on my google cloud.

Now after doing the `gcloud app deploy` the last thing I see on the screen is the message:

> nebula@0.0.0 start /app
>   ng serve
>
> sh: 1: ng: not found

and I am dead in the water.

I have tried so many different versions of `app.yaml` and `cloudbuild.yaml` file that I feel like i have not learned anything.

I have tried the same thing by starting with the very basic "Hero's" app and get the same issue.

i.e.

> ng new xxx
>   cd xxx
>   npm install
>   ng serve

Then I see the default Heros screen in my browser.

I then create this `app.yaml` file

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10


service: 
  xxx
```

I then try to deploy using:

> gcloud app deploy

When this finishes I get the message

> Deployed service [xxx] to [https://xxx-dot-project.appspot.com]

When I go to that url, I get:

> Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.

The log file for this run is:

```
    gcloud app logs tail -s xxx
    Waiting for new log entries...
    2019-05-04 15:27:35 xxx[20190504t102436]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:27:35 xxx[20190504t102436]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:28:56 xxx[20190504t102436]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:32:45 xxx[prod]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:32:50 xxx[prod]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:33:06 xxx[prod]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:33:10 xxx[prod]  "GET /run HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:33:10 xxx[prod]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:33:16 xxx[prod]  "GET /run HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:33:16 xxx[prod]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:33:19 xxx[prod]  "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:33:19 xxx[prod]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:40:43 xxx[prod]  "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:40:46 xxx[prod]  "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:40:50 xxx[prod]  "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:40:50 xxx[prod]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 15:40:53 xxx[prod]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404
    2019-05-04 16:01:50 xxx[20190504t105955]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
    2019-05-04 16:01:51 xxx[20190504t105955]  /bin/sh: 1: ng: not found
    2019-05-04 16:06:19 xxx[20190504t105955]  "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500
    2019-05-04 16:06:20 xxx[20190504t105955]  /bin/sh: 1: ng: not found
```

My question is can someone provide a trivial example of this process where the application runs in the google cloud?

Answer (score 0):

After project is created publish your project on GitHub.
On GitHub Apps you have to install Google Cloud Build now, because it needs access to your repositories.
You also have to create a Google Cloud Project for your new application and enable Cloud Build and Cloud App Engine.

Please refer here for more details:- 
https://medium.com/felixklauke/angular-google-cloud-build-app-engine-5e7c2038bdad

Comment: I appreciate your response and am trying to follow your suggestion. This is where i have issues.  I have tried that link.  But, first off it assumes I use GitHub Apps.  Though I do have a git account, I have no idea what is a GitHub App.  So now I have to learn all about GitHub Apps.   Secondly, the example referenced is in Python . I don't know python and my project is written in Javascript.  So now I have to learn another language to convert the Python example to a Javascript example.  I just wish I could find a  quickstart that takes the Angular Heros example and runs it as a Goggle App.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying Ng7 application with PHP backend, I would rather advise you to use two different solutions:

- [Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/quickstart) optimized for SPAs with CDN to deploy the Ng app (change your environment.ts to direct it to the AE endpoints. You will build your application first using `ng build` and then deploy the artifacts, so there is even no need for the Angular tooling in the resulting package.
- Use AppEngine to deploy your backend

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the suggestion to go to firebase was the most useable option.

I am a lot closer to where I want to be and I now see a lot of useful extras.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy a SPA (like Angular) with an [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref) similar to this:

```
runtime: nodejs10
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: dist/my-project/index.html
    upload: dist/my-project/index.html

  - url: /
    static_dir: dist/my-project
```

You'd need to build locally your angular project beforehand with a `ng build --prod`, otherwise you need to set a `predeploy` command on your package.json, which will be called by `gcloud app deploy` (e.g. `predeploy": "npm run lint && npm run build -- --prod --aot"`). Also important, you need to make sure you ignore all files outside of `dist` folder with `.gcloudignore` file. This will prevent google cloud to upload those files.

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud Platform
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore

# Node.js dependencies:
node_modules/
webpack.config.js
src/
tsconfig.json
readme.md
ssl/
tslint.json
LICENSE
.editorconfig
.dockerignore
.gitignore
```

https://github.com/mrdulin/angular-apollo-starter includes all those files